# Hide price excluding tax when price is empty

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a setup. For products, I display prices with VAT (info added in the suffix). However, I must include a net price under this price (only in single-product-view). In addition, I have products that are without a price and with them using the Call For Price plugin to display a button to send a price inquiry.

I display the net price adding:

```
<?php echo woocommerce_price ($ product-> get_price_excluding_tax ()); ?>
```

added in the template `/woocommerce/single-product/price.php`.

The problem is that in the case of a product without a price, I still see this value without tax (net) with the amount of 0.00. This one with VAT is deleted automatically.

How could I remove this net price in products that do not have the price indicated?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to add a condition :

`<?php if(woocommerce_price ($product-> get_price_excluding_tax ()) != '0.00') // If price is not equal to 0.00
{ echo woocommerce_price ($product-> get_price_excluding_tax ()); }

?>`

Let me know if it worked !

Comment: Unfortunately price is still visible. Product has set no price (empty price field) and displays on product page 0,00. If I set price to 0 for product, on page I see 0,00 with VAT and 0,00 (net)

Comment: hum... can we try with this ?

`<?php if( !empty(woocommerce_price ($product-> get_price_excluding_tax ()))) 
{ echo woocommerce_price ($product-> get_price_excluding_tax ()); }

?>`

Comment: Still 0,00 is visible